# r code for using Ornstein-Uhlenbeck to estimate time for mean reversion

Tags: r

I am looking for an example of the r code for using Ornstein-Uhlenbeck to estimate time for mean reversion when considering cointegrated securities

Answer (score 6):

Ref: Package ‘ouch’ [(link)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ouch/ouch.pdf)

Title: Ornstein-Uhlenbeck models for phylogenetic comparative hypotheses

```
prev_sprd <- c(sprd[2:length(sprd)], 0)
d_sprd <- sprd - prev_sprd
prev_sprd_mean <- prev_sprd - mean(prev_sprd)
sprd.zoo <- merge(d_sprd, prev_sprd_mean)
sprd_t <- as.data.frame(sprd.zoo)
```

#### with intercept:

```
result <- lm(d_sprd ~ prev_sprd_mean, data = sprd_t)
half_life <- -log(2)/coef(result)[2]
half_life
```

#### or if no intercept:

```
result = lm(d_sprd ~ prev_sprd_mean + 0,  data = sprd_t)   
half_life1 = -log(2)/coef(result)[1]
half_life1
```

also try:

[Statistical Methods for Financial Engineering, B. Remillard](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SMFI5/SMFI5.pdf)

[On the Simulation and Estimation of the Mean-Reverting Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process](http://commoditymodels.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/estimating-the-parameters-of-a-mean-reverting-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process1.pdf)

#### Why is this important?

If we enter into a mean-reverting position, and 3 or 4 half-life’s later the spread still has not reverted to zero, we have reason to believe that maybe the regime has changed, and our mean-reverting model may not be valid anymore

ref:

1. http://epchan.blogspot.co.uk/2007/01/what-is-your-stop-loss-strategy.html
2. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/peacots/peacots.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages on CRAN that have the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck procedure.  I would suggest using [rseek](http://www.rseek.org) to find them, then see which package best suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I suggestion reading through [this thread on the r-sig-finance list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck-td2991060.html) which directly addresses your question.

Comment: That came up in my rseek results. ;-)

Comment: @Joshua Absolutely; just wanted to highlight it since it goes over much more than just Ornstein-Uhlenbeck.